# Topology on $\mathbb R$, where intervals of the form $[a,b]$ are not closed (Examples)

Tags: general-topology

I want to find some examples of topologies on $\mathbb R$, where  intervals of the form $[a,b]$ are not closed.

I found only one example: it's subspace topology on $\mathbb R$, where interval, for example, $[0,1] = (-1,2) \cap [0,1]$ and $(-1,2)$ is open set of $\mathbb R$. So by definition of subspace topology $[0,1]$  is open in subset topology on $\mathbb R$.

But are there other examples?

Comment: Take the trivial topology $\tau = \{ \mathbb R , \emptyset \}$. Also, a set being open does not necessarily imply it is not closed, so I don’t think your example is correct.

Comment: Be careful with your example *open* is not the opposite of closed. In your example the interval $[0,1]$ is *still* closed, it just happens to also be open.

Comment: I don't understand your example. How does that define a topology on $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, for instance, the topology on $\mathbb R$ for wich a set $O\subset\mathbb R$ is open if and only if $O=\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus O$ is finite. For this topology (the cofinite topology) no interval $[a,b]$ (with $a<b$) is closed.

Comment: Can you explain me please why is it true? Because R\\(a,b) is not finite?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following topology on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ \tau=\lbrace\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\rbrace\cup \lbrace (x, \infty)\vert x\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace.$$
As you can see, closed intervals of the form $\left[a,b \right]$ with $a<b$ are not closed for this topology.